# How to skip comma if value is empty?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to create a message. Whether it is irrelevant in the html or ts file, it is only important that if a field is empty, skip comma ?

```
<span> Personal data: {{ data.firstName }} , {{ data.lastName }} , {{ data.age }}
```

At some point firstName or lastName or age is empty and then the comma remains unnecessary?
Example be:

Michael , , 21

or
, , 21 ..

I want if no value , no print comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it like this instead:

**Template**

```
<span> Personal data: {{ getPersonalData(data) }}</span>
```

**Component**

```
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {

   ...

   getPersonalData({ firstName = '', lastName = '', age = null }) {
      return `${firstName} ${lastName} ${age ? age : ''}`
        .split(' ')
        .filter(Boolean)
        .join(', ');
   }

}
```

**Alternative Solution**

`As per Michael Geary's concern below if in case either firstName or lastName has 2 or more words`

```
getPersonalData({ firstName = '', lastName = '', age = null }) {
  return Object
    .entries({ firstName, lastName, age })
    .map(([, value]) => value)
    .filter(Boolean)
    .join(', ');
}
```

---

Have created a **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-comma-separator?file=src/app/app.component.ts)** for your reference containing all various scenarios when either firstName, lastName, or age is empty.

Comment: What would happen if the first or last name contains a space? For example, `firstName="Guido"`, `lastName="van Rossum"`.

Comment: Hi @MichaelGeary that's a very good scenario. I have updated my answer above and also the Stackblitz Demo. Hope it helps with your concern :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to write your own code for this: in ts file you can create the following function:

```
f(data): string {
  let a: string[] = [];
  if(data.firstname && data.firstname != "") a.push(data.firstname);
  if(data.lastname && data.lastname != "") a.push(data.lastname);
  if(data.age && data.age != "") a.push(data.age);
  return a.join(" , ");
}
```

And later in the HTML side:

```
<span> Personal data: {{ f(data) }} </span>
```

Comment: Nice, this is much easier to understand than the accepted answer. Two suggestions: You can remove the first half of each `if` expression (e.g. `data.firstname &&`, and use `!==` instead of `!=`.

Comment: @MichaelGeary The first half is for checking if the property exists (and not null). If you are sure that all your objects have firstname, lastname and age properties then you don't need the first half, if don't you need it. Secondly I didn't use !== cause I don't know if age is number or string where you use it (But you are correct).

Answer (score 1):

Another clean solution:

Method:

```
calculateData(data: any) {
    return Object.keys(data).map(i => data[i] ? data[i] + ', ' : '').join('').slice(0,-2); 
}
```

And use like this:

```
<span> data: {{ calculateData(data) }}</span>
```

1. get an array of keys using Object.keys(data); // ['firstName', 'lastName', 'age'].
2. map those keys and get related data from data object using that keys
3. check is there any value, if exist, add it with a comma
4. join the final array (map result) to create a string
5. remove final comma and space using .slice() method

Answer (score 1):

1. [data.firstName, data.lastName, data.age ].filter(v=>v).join(" , ")
2. Object.values(data).filter(v=>v).join(" , ")

Comment: You don't need ".filter(v=>v)"

Comment: he wants if no value , no print comma.

Comment: You have the best answer imo... But I literally test it without ".filter(v=>v)" as it seemed redundant to me (Answer number 2).

Comment: What data is in the data you use?

Comment: I copied @KShewengger data. The users object here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-comma-separator?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: `v=>v` function and `Boolean` function here are the same

Comment: I didn't use his function. I used your answer with her data (only her data) Try yourself.